# Why does a nslookup on Amazon's DNS servers return NXDOMAIN?

Tags: networking, dns, nslookup

I ran `nslookup` on `amazon.com` and received:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   amazon.com
Address: 205.251.242.103
Name:   amazon.com
Address: 176.32.98.166
Name:   amazon.com
Address: 176.32.103.205
```

When I ran nslookup on these domains (for ex: 176.32.98.166) I received : `server can't find 166.98.32.176.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN` as the result.

It should resolve to a non-authoritative answer, should it not?

Answer (score 2):

Pointer (PTR) records allowing inverse DNS lookups (looking up a host name based on an IP address) are not required by the standards. In many cases it's not even a good idea, such as when a given IP address belongs to a server that might host many different host/domain names on it, such as a virtual web host, a CDN edge node, a load balancer for a cloud computing service, etc.

Comment: Well, there's also no requirement for PTRs to describe every single site _hosted_ on the server. If anything it would make the most sense for them to describe the server node _itself_, e.g. Google has names like `fra16s18-in-f14` to describe a CDN server in Frankfurt.